# How many JVM instances will create when we issue java command in different command prompts?

Tags: java, cmd, jvm

Can anyone please tell me how many jvm instances will created when we issue the following commands in different commands.

```
- command 1: c:\java -Xms32m -Xmx512m -Xss254k AccountSalary
- command 2: d:\java -Xms32m -Xmx512m -Xss254k AccountSalary
- command 3: c:\java -Xms32m -Xmx512m -Xss254k AccountSalary
```

Whether they will use save jvm heap size or for each java process different heap size?

Comment: Seriously? People are upvoting this?

Answer (score 6):

Each time you run the `java` command, you create a new JVM instances.  (And each JVM instance will be a distinct *process*.)

So, in your example, the number of JVM instances will be 3.

JVM instances do not share heaps.  Each one will have its own heap.  There is no saving of heap *space* by creating multiple heaps.  (In fact you probably use more heap space by creating multiple JVMs ... compared with running 3 instance of your application in the same JVM using multi-threading.)

The heap *sizes* are independent.  They are determined by the individual JVMs' command line options ...

---

With most JVMs, the only memory that is shared *between* JVM instances is the read-only segment containing the JVM code, and (possibly) shared native libraries.

Historically, there have been JVMs where compiled Java code can be shared between JVMs.  However, it is complicated, and (AFAIK) current generation JVMs don't support this.

Comment: thanks @stephen, my RAM is 2 GB memory , in the above case at a time 3 java process is running with different heap spaces, when iam running my application it is giving OutOfMemoryError: Heap Space error. how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @RajasekharBurepalli - If a JVM dies with an OOME, it either means that its heap is too small (for the problem you are trying to solve) or you have a memory leak.  You need to work out which.

Answer (score 0):

> Every process runs in its own JVM. and Heap space is not shared
>   amongst JVMs. Also, in your case, you have 3 different processes. So,
>   they run in their own JVMs.